# How to open a specific .DOCX document in LibreOffice always in Web View mode?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

How can I set a specific .DOCX document to automatically open always in LibreOffice Writer **Web View** mode? (Other Libre Office Writer documents should always open in normal page-view mode).

Comment: It's a property of the specific document. Set the document to web view and it should open in web view next time.

Comment: @DavidPostill Unfortunately, this is not the case with a .DOCX document.